# Can Entity Framework 6 import table and columns description data from SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm pretty new to both, so apologies if the answer is obvious, but I don't seem to be able to find any answers on this. SQL Server 2016 has a `Description` property for both tables and individual columns. Entity Framework 6 diagram has documentation - `Long Description` and `Documentation - Summary` properties for both tables and individual columns.

I update my EF diagrams from the database. Is it possible for EF6 to import the SQL Server description properties into one or other of the EF6 documentation properties? If so, what settings do I change?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Entity framework will connect to the SQL server through the Data Providers  and in your case the SqlClient, and I believe it will work

Answer (score 0):

Use code first from database with EF Reverse poco template, and configure it to include comments in summary block!

Comment: Thanks, Erik, but, as stated, I'm fairly new to this.  I've found the EF Reverse POCO generator on line and see it has the ability to include comments.  I presume I would need to replace the code currently generated by the EF6 with the code generated by the EF Reverse POCO generator.  Being a bit of a newbie, I'm not sure whether this would be a simple exercise eg. change the name of the DBcontext, but the property names for generated classes will be the same, so no further work, or whether there will be a lot to change.  Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Why not give it a try?

Comment: I did start to try it but found it produces documents in C#, whereas I am using VB.  I understand I could generate the documents in a separate C# project and reference them from the VB project, but it's sounding a little more complicated than I'd like it to be. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem of Entity framework is with Always Encrypted feature that shipped with SQL server 2016. This problem will appear in the Code first approach.

Based on this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/08/27/using-always-encrypted-with-entity-framework-6/)

> Entity Framework 6 was not designed from the start to work with the
>   Always Encrypted feature of SQL Server 2016. However, a lot of effort
>   has gone into making the feature work as transparently as possible
>   with existing code. This article explores the limitations you will
>   need to work around and the potential issues you should be aware of if
>   you need to make your application based on Entity Framework 6 work
>   with a database containing encrypted columns.

and the author proposed a workaround in all designing approach, Model first, Code first

**Suggestions**

- If you want to use the database with Entity Framework 6.1.3 without having nightmares that your code will work or not, you can set the compatibility mode to SQL Server 2014 for your database.
- Make sure that you are using the last `.NET framework`, right now `4.6.2`, which contains enhancements on the `SqlClient` for `Always Encrypted`.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks, Hadi, but I am using a data first approach without the Always Encrypted feature in the SQL database, so am not sure this is the anwer.

Comment: then its easy for you to make reverse engineering ( search from tools -> extensions and updates -> in the online search put `EntityFramework Reverse Poco Generator`, and use it to retrieve all the classes you need). It will work with you since as I mentioned in the comments on your question, Entity framework uses ADO.NET to connect to SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is not currently possible with EF but you could do something like this to retrieve the Description property:

[image: column properties]

```
 SELECT value from fn_listextendedproperty( 
    'MS_Description', 
    'schema', 'dbo', 
    'table', 'Log', 
    'column', 'EventID')
```

Results:

[image: results]

Code Example:

```
public static class DbHelpers
{
    public static string GetColumnDocumentation(string tableName, string columnName, SqlConnection connection)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [value] 
                                                        FROM fn_listextendedproperty (
                                                        'MS_Description', 
                                                        'schema', 'dbo', 
                                                        'table', @TableName, 
                                                        'column', @columnName)", connection))
                {

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("TableName", tableName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ColumnName", columnName);

                    return command.ExecuteScalar() as String;
        }
    }
}
```